# login form redirect domain via iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

Is it possible? If I insert a login form from example website `wwww.web1.com` into my website `www.mysite.com` and when I click the login button the page would still show `www.mysite.com` and show session login `www.web1.com` into iframe.

```
        <form  action="http://www.web1.com/" method="post" name="form1" >
                    <table width="326" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-left:7px; padding-right:7px; width:1px; border-right:1px solid #1e639e;">
                                <img src="logo1.png" height="32px" border="0"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left:7px; width:1px; white-space:nowrap;">
                                <input name="textfield" type="text" class="input_text" placeholder="Username"/>
                                <input name="textfield2" type="password" class="input_text" placeholder="Password"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="http://www.web1.com/app/autonum.php" align="absmiddle">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="Authnum" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" class="za_text" style=" width: 56px; ">
                            </td>
                            <td width="68"><input name="login" type="submit" class="but_submit" id="login" value="LOGIN"/></td>
                            <!--<td width="65">
                                <a href="register.php" class="iframe">
                                    <div class="but_join" style="width:60px;">JOIN NOW</div>
                                </a>
                            </td>-->
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
```